# Is binary search possible on vectors?

Tags: c++, arrays, search, vector, binary-search

I know Binary search works on sorted arrays as it is possible to access the middle element in unit time, due to array indexing. But in lists it would take linear time to access the middle element, making binary search pointless. Vectors have flexible size like lists so  if they're implemented using lists,binary search shouldn't work on them right? Or do vectors use arrays with dynamic memory allocation and will binary search work in that case? (I'm a beginner so please point out any flaws in my logic)

Comment: How a vector is implemented(from user's perspective) is not as important as how it behaves. The standard mandates behavior not implementation.

Comment: A `std::vector` is a dynamically-sized array. [This](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a good site for looking things up. And [this book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) is another good resource. (If vectors were implemented as linked lists they would be pointless, since they would just be linked lists.)

Comment: A vector is a kind of dynamic *array*. It's really just a wrapper around a heap-allocated array. Though not that it really matters, any indexable and "array-like" container could be used for binary search just like any actual array.

Comment: @naruto4526 std::vector has random access iterators. So the search will be efficient as with arrays.

Answer (score 8):

> *Vectors have flexible size like lists so if they're implemented using lists*

Vectors cannot be implemented using linked lists.  It is a requirement of `std::vector` that it has constant-time access by numeric index, and that the values are stored contiguously like an array.  So binary search is perfectly fine, so long as the values are kept sorted.